# Mekor Chaim by the Chavauss Yo'ir

Tags: product-recommendation, shulchan-aruch, acharonim, yekke

Where can I find a copy of the Mekor Chaim by R' Yair Bacharach זצ”ל (the Chavot Ya'ir)? I read on Wikipedia that Machon Yerushalayim publishes a copy, but a perusal of their catalogue does not turn up any results. A search on HebrewBooks.org similarly turns up empty (although there are plenty of sefarim entitled מקור חיים found there), as does a search of Harvard's library catalogue (HOLLIS).

Comment: It's in the Otzar: http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?147069& You're looking for a print copy, I assume?

Comment: @DoubleAA, ideally. I don't have an account with Otzar and I can't learn from them on Shabbos or yontif anyway

Comment: You may be able to access it through a university/alumni/library. IAE in those first 40 preview pages you could get info about print editions.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'll check Hollis. FWIW, the edition on Otzar is the one referenced in the OP

Comment: ^Update: Harvard libraries (HOLLIS) lack any volume with the title of Meqor Ḥayyim (their transliteration of מקור חיים) which is surprising, considering the size of their Judaica collection.